# How to test backPressure in RxJava using Observable?

Tags: java, observable, flowable

I want to understand the the need for Flowable in RxJava. So I want to deal with backPressure for huge data with simple Observable. But I am not getting any error with it. 
this is my test code:

```
Observable.range(1, 10000).observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(@NonNull Integer integer) {
                System.out.println("next: " + integer);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                System.out.println("onError " + e.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }

        });
try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How can I test backPressure problems using Observable? Thanks

Comment: Can you please help me to solve my question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60925265/6097074